# Versions of Python & Spark to work with VS Code Notebooks

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, pyspark, aws-glue

I'm developing scripts for AWS Glue, and trying to mimic development environment as close as possible to their specs [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/release-notes.html). Since it's a bit costly to run a Notebook server/development endpoint, I set everything up on local machine instead, develop scripts on VS Code Notebook, due to its usefulness.

There're some troubles with Notebook setup due to incompatible versions between installed Python & Spark.

- For Python, I have gone through some harsh time to clean up, and its version is 3.8.3 now
- For Spark, I use the manual method with version of 2.4.3, since I plan to use Scala alongside at later time. I install the `findspark` package to load that  version as expected.

*And it doesn't work!* The error was [`TypeError: an integer is required (got type bytes)`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n8R4F.png)

I've searched around, and people said to downgrade to Python 3.7 using `pyenv`, and I got 3.7.7 installed but still had the same error

As a last resort, I tried `pip install pyspark`. it's Spark 3.0.0, and works fine, but not as expected.

Hope there's someone have experiences of this matter

Answer (score 0):

A better approach would be to install the glue dependencies on docker then ssh into that docker container using VS code to mimic exact glue local dev environment.

I've written a blog about the same if you like to refer

https://towardsdatascience.com/develop-glue-jobs-locally-using-docker-containers-bffc9d95bd1